# What virtue prolonged Robert Baratheon's sovereignty?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Kings Landing is rendered as a veritable pit of Vipers, with each component constantly forwarding their own ambitions through murder and subterfuge. This is especially true of people of power: Advisors, Dignitaries, Challengers from other Royal Households.

[image]

Whilst I'm aware that the death of Robert Baratheon served as a catalyst for the events of *A Song of Ice and Fire*, was Kings Landing a considerably more hospitable place in support of a King's longevity *before* Baratheon's death, or was there some capability/factor that Robert possessed that meant he was able to reign unopposed for so long, and managed what seems to be an impossible feat: a sovereignty that didn't result in him being deposed/murdered?

The entire series is an exploration of Statecraft, with different elements pursuing different strategies in order to consolidate power within their own reach. Is this a behavior that truly only emerged at the death of Robert, or did Baratheon suffer the same incessant duplicity and scheming from his subjects?

### What advantage did Robert have, that he was able to propser for so long?

A conversation between Tywin and Tommen in [Breaker of Chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaker_of_Chains) would suggest that Robert's legacy lay in his 'Strength', which ultimately proved to be his downfall.

It's unlikely this is a reference to his physical constitution, so is there some further diplomatic factor attributed to Robert's longevity? If so, what is it?

Comment: Are you asking why fighting only broke out after Robert's death?

Comment: I'm asking why Robert was able to stay on the throne so long without meeting a grisly end, if everyone in the political arena of Westeros behaves with such ambitious Machiavellianism.

Comment: Without wanting to state the obvious, surely it's because all five of the "five kings" (Joffrey Baratheon, Stannis Baratheon, Renly Baratheon, Robb Stark and Balon Greyjoy)  support Robert Baratheon.

Comment: I understand that you're saying the kingdom was in relative harmony, but are you suggesting that there was no power-play before he was killed? all were happy with their station, and were less ambitious personalities? I'm not being dismissive, I'm asking if this was a genuine answer, and if so, please post as answer and elaborate? you Address the issue of the revolting 'Five Kings', but what about the other manipulators and calculating characters that, in some cases, have already demonstrated a proclivity for regicide?

Comment: No-one with any armies worth mentioning were willing to stand against him. Anyone that openly defied him was cruising for a bruising and while there were clearly lots of people that *wanted* him dead, there weren't any that were willing to actually do the deed.

Comment: Robert Baratheon did die a grisly death, and it's been a while since I read the first book, but isn't it at least implied the wild boar might have received a little extra "help"?

Comment: @AndresF. it's more than implied, it's about as close as you get in GoT to being admitted openly that Cersei bribed Lancel with sex to make sure Robert got black-out-drunk before the hunt.

Comment: @AndresF,:  I think its fair to say his death was wanted (and facilitated), but a hunting accident is a bit of a stretch to claim his murder was in some way orchestrated, no matter how much Cersei made sure he was drunk to heighten the probability.

Comment: Robert Baratheon may have been an inept leader and an idiot, besides. But he was a [*useful* idiot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useful_idiot), by golly.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional It has been verified by both Lancel and Cersei in the books that they exchanged his strongwine with wine 3 times as strong. They knew it would put him in mortal danger, so it is murder, and it is premeditated.

Comment: @TLP, I think we're digressing from the point a little bit here, but even lacing Robert's wine does not constitute Cersei as comitting murder. If we're being especially litigious,  we could stretch to saying she was an accessory to suicide or deliberate endangerment,  but to call what is ultimately an accidental death 'pre-meditated murder' is something I'm unwilling to accept so candidly.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional I'm challenging your assumption that Robert wasn't opposed or murdered, and that he was somehow "special". It is obvious Cersei hated being married to him; right there you have a powerful disident within the court. She also might have murdered him, though this is less clear. So you are in effect begging the question: _nothing_ in King Robert's reign marks him as particularly different from the other kings. He conquered his position through force of arms, reigned some years, was hated by his queen, and died in a grisly way. What makes him different?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional If you take an action that you know will put a person in lethal danger, and your intent is that they die, then you are a murderer. And it is pretty clear in the books that it was Cersei's intent that he die.

Comment: @TLP, I **wish** the legal system was as black and white as this, ha ha ha!... still, perhaps Cersei bribed the the boar... or seduced him ;) This article has an answer, and it's more oriented around the *relative* success of his reign in regards to the individuals who supported his regency rather than the circumstances of his eventual death.  Thanks for contributing though!

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional I'm talking about what really happened, not what some court would decide. If you're interested in the topic, you should check out the theory of the conspiracy against Aerys. I forget what they called it, but basically the main culprits were Jon Arryn, Hoster Tully, and Rickard Stark. I think it was called something like "Southron Ambitions".

Comment: @TLP: “I'm talking about what really happened, not what some court would decide.” I’m afraid courts *are* the ones who decide what “murder” is and what it isn’t, because it’s a legal term.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Don't be afraid, it's not terminal. Yes, it is murder. If you want to believe otherwise, then go right ahead. And don't resurrect this old, dumb argument. Its just splitting hairs.

Comment: @TLP: THAT’S FOR THE COURTS TO DECIDE, IMPUDENT... imp?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to start a little earlier. The catalyst for the events of *A Song of Ice and Fire* was not the death of Robert, but the death of Jon Arryn.  Jon Arryn fostered both Robert and Ned Stark and was very much like a father to both of them. After Robert became king, Jon Arryn became the Hand of the King and a *de facto* ruler of the Seven Kingdoms.

Robert was a good fighter, and he also had personal charisma, which allowed him to turn many of his enemies into friends.  However, he was completely inept as a peace-time ruler, and it was Jon Arryn who kept the kingdom together. This is why immediately after Jon Arryn's death, Robert set out for Winterfell to tell Ned to be his new Hand. Robert wanted nothing to do with the day-to-day business of running a kingdom, and he desperately needed a replacement for Jon Arryn. Unfortunately, it turned out that Ned Stark was far less qualified than his mentor, which is one of the causes of the War of Five Kings.

So, the answer to your main question about what made Robert so unique is Jon Arryn, who was a very shrewd politician. He was able to deal with the snake pit that is Kings Landing, and keep all the great houses in line for 15 years. All Robert could do by himself was bankrupt his realm.

Comment: While this is all true, it doesn't actually answer the question of how Robert Baratheon maintaned his life/rule over Westeros without opposition.

Comment: @Monty129: Still working on the answer. :)

Comment: @Monty129: Ok, now I am done. :)

Comment: This is interesting. It suggests that the Baratheon dynasty was in some part a puppet government: or was at least Stewarded by another political figure. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional that's not far from the truth: Robert almost immediately made allies of the Lannisters, who held most of the money (and thus power) in Westeros, and he was allied with Jon Arryn and Ned Stark, the respective military powers in the North and East.

Comment: Your last sentence leads to an interesting detail question: Robert certainly didn't bankrupt the realm in the short time between John Arryn's death and Ned Stark's shocked discovery of how deeply the crown was indebted. So why did John Arryn not prevent this if he was such a skilled politician?

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: A skilled administrator has the ability to delegate. In this instance, the Crown's finances were being managed by Littlefinger, who would have assured Jon that all was well. It would have been unwise of Jon to trust Littlefinger, but he wouldn't be the first or last person to make that mistake. Also, we see that Robert was prone to impulsive spending on things like the Hand's Tournament; probably Jon was no better than Ned at reining in Robert's extravagance.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Small detail: it was John Arryn who arranged Robert's marriage to Cercei, securing an alliance with the richest of the great houses. Arryn himself married Lysa Tulley to ensure the loyalty of the Riverlands. The only political decisions Robert has made himself as king was to appoint Ned as the new hand and to order the death of Deanerys.

Answer (score 15):

Without wishing to state the obvious, Robert Baratheon was largely immune from the sorts of external threats that led to the "War of the Five Kings" because the main protagonists (e.g. those that were sufficiently powerful to oppose him) were either cowed by him or directly owed their position to his patronage;

Joffrey Baratheon is his son (ahem), Stannis and Renly are his brothers (both with their own lands and titles), Robb Stark's father was his oldest friend and bondsman (again with lands and titles) and Balon Greyjoy was loyal to Robert on pain of having his son and heir killed.

With regards to smaller threats (assassination, etc) it's pretty clear that the [small council](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Small_council#Under_Robert_Baratheon) were well equipped to identify and deal with likely threats against the king. On top of which Robert was well-regarded by his people due to the stability he provided after the various rebellions of the past decades. He also had a cadre of ultra-loyal guards to protect his life.

Comment: Again it's pretty obvious, but the Lannisters were bound to Robert by his marriage to Cersei; they had one of their own as Queen and the next King would be (ahem) half Lannister. Jon Arryn, Lord of the Vale, was a friend and mentor of Robert. The Martells despised Robert, but were willing to wait patiently for their revenge. Finally, Robert's "strength" was in war. When Balon Greyjoy rebelled, Robert ruthlessly defeated him in battle, killed his two elder sons and took Theon hostage. There was plenty of intrigue between different factions, but no military rebellion until after Robert's death.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - You've hit the nail on the head. Lots of intrigue but all the interested parties were better off with him alive. The whole war would probably never have happened if Ned had been smart enough to keep his mouth shut or had Joffrey been smart enough just to send him packing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So you're saying King Robert didn't neccesarily possess any virtues that made him a 'good king', but was fortunate enough to rule at a time when he had no natural enemies (save for the Targaryen Children): and as such had no need for guile?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional - I don't think it's fair to characterise him as a man with "no virtues". He was loyal and brave, generous to his friends, blessed with an excellent choice in aides and ruthless to his enemies. He might have *personally* lacked guile but he certainly employed people with plenty of it.

Answer (score 14):

A lot of very good answers here, and I don't disagree with them but I'm going to add a different viewpoint: I challenge the question's very premise.

Robert I Baratheon's reign was not that long and was not that peaceful. Robert ruled only for 15 years and his reign was punctuated by three violent episodes: the war to win the throne, the Greyjoy uprising, and the skirmishes between the Lannisters and the Tullys that eventually turned into the War of the Five Kings.

Let's look at longevity. Here are the previous owners of the Iron Throne along with the length of their reign:

```
Aegon I "The Conqueror"     36 years  
    Founder of the Targaryen royal dynasty. Unified six of the seven kingdoms.

Aenys I                     5 years  
    Weak king. The Faith of the Seven rebelled against his rule.

Maegor I "The Cruel"        6 years  
    Brutally fought against the Faith of the Seven uprising. Killed in unknown 
    circumstances.

Jaehaerys I "The Wise"      55 years  
    Negotiated peace with the Faith in return of them disbanding their militant 
    arm. His reign is regarded as the longest and most peaceful. 

Viserys I                   27 years
    Continued the peaceful reign of his grandfather, and groomed his eldest daughter 
    Rhaenyra to be the first female Targaryen ruler.

Aegon II "The Usurper"      2 years
    Rebelled against his older half sister Rhaenyra in a ruinous civil war known as
    the Dance of the Dragons and took the throne for himself. History of that conflict
    is told in the novella "The Princess and the Queen". Died with no male issue of 
    wounds inflicted during the conflict.

Aegon III "The Dragonbane"  26 years
    Rhaenyra's son. Hated dragons due to the events in the Dance of Dragons. The last
    of the Targaryen dragons died during his reign.

Daeron I "The Young Dragon" 4 years
    At 16 he was the youngest Targaryen king to assume the Iron Throne. Conquered Dorne, 
    but eventually lost it again and died trying to hold it.

Baelor I "The Blessed"      10 years
    Highly religious king who shunned worldly pleasures and Targaryen incest. Negotiated 
    peace with Dorne by arranging a marriage between the Targaryens and the Martells.
    Starved himself to death in an attempt to cleanse himself from lust.

Viserys II                  1 year
    Was Hand of the King to his nephews Daeron I and Baelor I, and ruled while the former 
    warred and the latter prayed. Assumed the throne for a short while before dying, 
    possibly of old age.

Aegon IV "The Unworthy"     12 years
    Considered by many as the worst Targaryen king. Sired countless bastards all
    across the realm. Just before he died he legitimized several of the nobly born
    ones (known the as the Great Bastards), eventually causing the Blackfyre Rebellion
    that plunged the realm into civil war again.

Daeron II "The Good"        25 years
    Defeated his bastard-born half-brother Daemon Blackfyre and secured the throne.
    Negotiated the assimilation of Dorne into the kingdom. Died during the Great
    Spring Sickness.

Aerys I                     12 years
    Regarded as a weak and bookish king, who left the ruling to his uncle and Hand 
    Brynden Rivers, who was one of the Great Bastards who sided with the Targaryens.
    His reign was plagued by a great drought and conflicts with the Iron Islands.

Maekar I                    12 years
    When he took the throne he relieved Brynden Rivers of his duties and imprisoned
    him. Died fighting a rebel lord, probably a remnant of the Blackfyre Rebellion.

Aegon V "The Unlikely"      26 years
    Named the unlikely because he was the fourth son of a fourth son (of a king).
    In his youth he roamed the Seven Kingdoms as a Hedge Knight's squire (as told in 
    the Dunk and Egg novellas). Sent Brynden Rivers to the Wall. Obsessed with returning
    dragons to Westeros. Died in the mysterious event known as the Tragedy of Summerhall. 
    He is the brother of Maester Aemon of the Night's Watch.

Jaehaerys II                3 years
    Sickly king who died young, but ruled well according to Ser Barristan Selmy.

Aerys II "The Mad King"     21 years
    The last of the Targaryen kings. Succumbed to the famed Targaryen madness. His
    handling of the Rhaegar Targaryen/Lyanna Stark affair escalated into Robert's
    Rebellion. Killed by his Kingsguard: Ser Jaime Lannister. Father of Daenerys.
```

What we find is that Robert's reign is below the average of 22.5 set by his Targaryen predecessors (though he is a bit above the median of 12).

Robert, however, benefits from the fact that his direct predecessor was Aerys II (AKA The Mad King). A king who, in his later years at least, was feared and loathed by the nobles and the commons alike. While Robert might have had many flaws, he never roasted his enemies alive in their armor. This results in Robert being remembered more favorably.

Further, his reign was not devoid of underhanded political machinations. He simply avoided liquidation because he was not really an obstacle in front of anyone. Robert was truly king in name only, with the real power floating somewhere around his Hand (Jon Arryn) and the members of the Small Council. It wasn't until a feud erupted between the Lannisters and Starks/Tullys did Robert become a target since now he had to choose one side over the other.

Comment: This answer seems to support Dima's answer. I'm not sure 15 years worth of relatively stable rule is something to be sniffed at though!

Comment: Robert never did definitively choose sides in the Stark/Lannister feud. (The Mountain was outlawed and Beric Dondarrion's men were sent by Ned in his capacity as Hand.) Cersei despised Robert and feared the truth about her children's parentage would come out, so she was already looking for an opportunity to murder Robert and put Joffrey on the throne.

Comment: Just out of interest, could you adjust your answer to reflect what the final fate was of those listed? how many suffered a downfall/deposition, and how many reigned in relative peace?

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - Yeah but before Ned arrived she could always wait until Robert eventually died from liver disease and/or an STD. Now that Ned was getting too close for comfort, Robert getting off his fat royal ass and siding with the Starks was a real possibility.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional - Tall order! But I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional - There you go!

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This is a valuable resource in the debate.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't mark both questions as correct, but as yours elaborates on Dima's (which was slightly quicker), I have to give him the little Green fella. Much obliged, though.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional - No problem. By now I've amassed enough points that I don't really care about that stuff anymore. Now excuse me while I go swim in my safe filled with points. :P

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand that the death of a king won't necessarily benefit you.  The job, then, is to make your continued reign as advantageous to as many people as possible, and your death as disadvantageous to as many people as possible.

Baratheon did suffer the same attempts on his life that other kings did.  It was largely his hand, Jon Arryn, who forestalled most of those attempts, though some were doubtless stopped by others.  Most were stopped by forming alliances with other houses, particularly strong, scheming, or otherwise powerful houses that may have been looked over in previous reigns.

Marrying Robert to House Lannister was a good start.  Marrying the hand to the House Tully helped cement things in another quarter.  Further, the reign and line were new - there were not as many people in the list of royal succession based on Robert's gain of the throne.  As a new line, he had very few people other than direct descendants who could legitimately take the throne in the event of his demise.

Once the Hand died, though, it was essential not only to replace him with someone the King could trust that would protect him from subterfuge, it was necessary to bring the House Tully back into the fold.  Ned was the obvious choice, not only because he was a strong friend of Robert, but because his wife is of the House Tully.

Once the King had heirs that survived past boyhood, then the line could essentially be cemented, and the death of the king shouldn't matter as much because killing the king won't necessarily change the power structure appreciably.  Only killing the king prior to heirs, or killing them *and* all their heirs will change the power structure significantly.

If one had to choose a single thing that prolonged his reign, it would be Jon Arryn, making sure the alliances were properly cemented, and discouraging attacks.

What Jon didn't see, for well over a decade, was that Robert had no natural born heirs. It was his realization of this that led to his death.  Once he understood that Robert had no sons of his own through Cersei, he started looking at all Robert's Bastards to see if any could be legitimized.  Bringing the information forth prior to establishing his legacy would have put him in more danger, he believed, than he was already in with the Lannisters being largely in power.

It took significant effort for various machinations to work in a way that Jon would die at the hands of someone he didn't suspect.  Once that was accomplished, though, it was easier to kill Robert.

It is unlikely that Robert could have been disposed of while Jon Arryn still lived and acted in his capacity as the King's Hand.  It is unlikely that Robert would have ever dismissed Jon as King's Hand while he still lived.

Therefore Jon Arryn was responsible for Robert's relatively lengthy reign.